# Two CalendarExtenders?

Tags: c#, .net, date, format, calendarextender

I have a popup ajax calendarextender that populates a text box with the selected date, (MM/dd/yyyy). This works. I want to capture the same date in an additional text box with a different format (yyyyMMdd). The first is for display and the second date is a parameter for gridview query. Is this done with two calandarextenders? (btw I'm using C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supplying one to a query, you could just change the parameter value in code before supplying it to the [query](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).

```
 var datetimeForQuery = extenderVariable.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Clever, thanks. Does it matter if I use "var" or "string"? What section of the code behind would this go in to? I have two method that generate the query, I can't seem to get it to "fit" (won't compile) in the those methods, is there a better place?

Comment: you can use string, this would go in the method that builds your query